# Como cadastrar usuário com o modo editável desativado usando angularjs e xeditable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xeditable

Gostaria que o dado já tivesse feito um trigger no "save", ou algo do tipo, na hora de incluir o usuário, ele aparecer sem estar no modo de edição.

Veja meu exemplo no [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/daumba15/).

Como poderia resolver isso?

Estou usando [**esta biblioteca**](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/).

**Obs:** mais detalhes da questão está na resposta do comentário do Lucas.

Comment: Eu não consegui entender direito qual a dúvida @IvanFerrer.

Comment: Oi Lucas, se vc notar no exemplo do fiddle, quando crio um usuário novo, ele vem com os campos editáveis na tabela (com inputs), veja que eu já preenchi os dados, então não preciso editar, nem salvar, era para carregar apenas mais uma linha na tabela. Eu gostaria de faze isso direto, sem precisar clicar em save.

Comment: A ideia é que a edição seja posterior à inclusão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri como fazer funcionar:

É so colocar isso na tag do form:

```
<form shown="false">
```